# Javascript check if an index equals a number

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to check if the current active index equals to a number in the following way:

8, 16, 24, 32, 40 and so on... If that's the case then the console should print out: Go down.

The described part above works fine, but I can't seem to get the opposite part working.

---

Let's say my currentIndex equals to 12 then the next possible go down index would be 16 (Works fine) and the next possible index to go up would be 9 since its only showing 8 items each time.
Now I need to check if the currentIndex equals to 8 + 1 / 16 + 1 / 24 + 1 / 32 + 1 / 40 + 1 ...
 So the console would print out Go up.

How could I create my `else if` to achieve this?

```
var shownItems = 8;
var currentIndex = 12;

// Check if the currentIndex equals 8 / 16 / 24 / 32 / 40 ...
if(currentIndex / shownItems % 1 === 0) {
    console.log("Go down");
}
// Check if the currentIndex equals 8 - 7 / 16 - 7 / 24 - 7 / 32 - 7 / 40 - 7
else if() {
    console.log("Go up");
}
```

Comment: Hint: `anyNumber % 1 === 0`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check for:

```
 (currentIndex + 1) % shownItems === 0
```

Comment: Thanks, just had to change - 1 to + 1 and works fine!

Comment: @pr0b glad to help :)